# cannot be cast to extend class

Tags: java, data-structures

Hello I try to write code of AVLTree extend BST  Before 4h it works but now no i dont know why. i just add some comment in code.

error :

```
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.ClassCastException: Arbre$Noeud cannot be cast to ArbreAVL$NoeudAVL
    at ArbreAVL.insertion(ArbreAVL.java:162)
    at Test.main(Test.java:9)
```

Code:

```
public class Arbre {
protected Noeud racine;

protected static class Noeud {
    protected int data;
    protected Noeud filsG;
    protected Noeud filsD;

    public Noeud(int data, Noeud filsG, Noeud filsD) {
        this.data = data;
        this.filsG = filsG;
        this.filsD = filsD;
    }

    public Noeud(int data) {
        this.data = data;
        this.filsD = null;
        this.filsG = null;
    }

}

public Arbre() {
    this.racine = null;
}

public Arbre(int data) {
    this.racine = new Noeud(data);
}

public Arbre(int data, Noeud filsG, Noeud filsD) {
    this.racine = new Noeud(data, filsG, filsD);
}

/*
 * L’adjonction d’un nouvel élément à un arbre modifie l’arbre.
 */
public void insertion(int data) {
    this.racine = insertion(this.racine, data);
}

private Noeud insertion(Noeud racine, int data) {
    if (racine == null)
        return new Noeud(data);
    if (data < racine.data)
        racine.filsG = insertion(racine.filsG, data);
    else
        racine.filsD = insertion(racine.filsD, data);
    return racine;
}

/*
 * Une méthode booléenne qui teste la présence d’un élément dans l’arbre
 */
public boolean recherche(int data) {
    return recherche(this.racine, data);
}

private boolean recherche(Noeud racine, int data) {
    if (racine == null)
        return false;
    else {
        if (data < racine.data)
            return recherche(racine.filsG, data);
        else if (data > racine.data)
            return recherche(racine.filsD, data);
        else
            return true;
    }
}

/*
 * 
 */
public void suppMin() {
    if (this.racine != null)
        this.racine = suppMin(this.racine);
}

private Noeud suppMin(Noeud n) {
    if (n.filsG == null)
        return n.filsD;
    n.filsG = suppMin(n.filsG);
    return n;
}

/*
 * recherche le nœud portant la clé à supprimer
 */
public void supprimer(int data) {
    this.racine = supprimer(this.racine, data);
}

/*
 * recherche le nœud portant la clé à supprimer
 */
private Noeud supprimer(Noeud n, int data) {
    if (n == null)
        return null;
    if (data < n.data)
        n.filsG = supprimer(n.filsG, data);
    else if (data > n.data)
        n.filsD = supprimer(n.filsD, data);
    else {
        if (n.filsD == null)
            return n.filsG;
        if (n.filsG == null)
            return n.filsD;
        Noeud t = n;
        n = getMin(t.filsD);
        n.filsD = suppMin(t.filsD);
        n.filsG = t.filsG;
    }
    return n;
}

private Noeud getMin(Noeud n) {
    if (n == null)
        return null;
    else if (n.filsG == null)
        return n;
    else
        return getMin(n.filsG);
}

public int hauteur() {
    return hauteur(this.racine);
};

public int hauteur(Noeud n) {
    if (n == null)
        return -1;
    else
        return 1 + Math.max(hauteur(n.filsG), hauteur(n.filsD));
}

public boolean isVide() {
    return (this.racine == null);

}

public Noeud getRacine() {
    return racine;
}

public void setRacine(Noeud racine) {
    this.racine = racine;
}

/*
 * Serialisation
 * @see java.lang.Object#toString()
 */
public String toString() {
    return toString(this.racine);
}

private String toString(Noeud n) {
    if (n == null)
        return "()";
    else {
        String s = "(";
        s = s + toString(n.filsG);
        s = s + "," + n.data + ",";
        s = s + toString(n.filsD);
        return s + ")";
    }

}
```

}

```
public class ArbreAVL extends Arbre{
protected class NoeudAVL extends Noeud {
    protected int factorEquilibre;

    public NoeudAVL(int cle, Noeud filsG, Noeud filsD, int b) {
        super(cle, filsG, filsD);
        this.factorEquilibre = b;
    }

    public NoeudAVL(int cle) {
        super(cle);
        this.factorEquilibre = 0;
    }

    /*
     * Une rotation rééquilibre une partie de l’arbre en réarrangeant les
     * nœuds tout en préservant la propriété qui fait que le nœud gauche est
     * plus petit que son père, qui est lui même inférieur à son fils droit;
     * cette propriété doit être maintenue pour que l’arbre reste un arbre
     * binaire de recherche. Après la rotation, les facteurs d’équilibre de
     * tous les nœuds du sous-arbre équilibré sont +1, −1 et 0. Il n’y a que
     * quatre types de rotations à réaliser : les GG (gauche-gauche), GD
     * (gauche-droite), DD (droite-droite) et DG (droite-gauche).
     */
    protected NoeudAVL rotationG() {
        NoeudAVL oldRacine = this;
        NoeudAVL newRacine = (NoeudAVL) filsD;
        oldRacine.filsD = newRacine.filsG;
        newRacine.filsG = oldRacine;
        int a = oldRacine.factorEquilibre;
        int b = newRacine.factorEquilibre;
        if (b <= 0) {
            newRacine.factorEquilibre = (a >= 1) ? b - 1 : a + b - 2;
            oldRacine.factorEquilibre = a - 1;
        } else {
            newRacine.factorEquilibre = (a <= b) ? a - 2 : b - 1;
            oldRacine.factorEquilibre = a - b - 1;
        }
        return newRacine;
    }

    protected NoeudAVL rotationD() {
        NoeudAVL oldRacine = this;
        NoeudAVL newRacine = (NoeudAVL) filsG;
        oldRacine.filsG = newRacine.filsD;
        newRacine.filsD = oldRacine;
        int a = oldRacine.factorEquilibre;
        int b = newRacine.factorEquilibre;
        if (b <= 0) {
            newRacine.factorEquilibre = (b > a) ? b + 1 : a + 2;
            oldRacine.factorEquilibre = a - b + 1;
        } else {
            newRacine.factorEquilibre = (a < 0) ? b + 1 : a + b + 2;
            oldRacine.factorEquilibre = a + 1;
        }
        return newRacine;
    }

    protected NoeudAVL reequilibreG(int oldfactorEquilibre) {
        if ((NoeudAVL) filsG == null) {
            factorEquilibre++;
        } else if ((((NoeudAVL) filsG).factorEquilibre == 0)
                && (oldfactorEquilibre != 0)) {
            factorEquilibre++;
        }
        return (factorEquilibre > 1) ? equilibrer() : this;
    }

    protected NoeudAVL reequilibreD(int oldfactorEquilibre) {
        if ((NoeudAVL) filsD == null) {
            factorEquilibre--;
        } else if ((((NoeudAVL) filsD).factorEquilibre == 0)
                && (oldfactorEquilibre != 0)) {
            factorEquilibre--;
        }
        return (factorEquilibre < -1) ? equilibrer() : this;
    }

    /*
     * La méthode principale implante l’algorithme de rééquilibrage
     */
    protected NoeudAVL equilibrer() {
        if (factorEquilibre < 0) {
            if (((NoeudAVL) filsG).factorEquilibre <= 0)
                return rotationD();
            else {
                filsG = ((NoeudAVL) filsG).rotationG();
                return rotationD();
            }
        } else {
            if (((NoeudAVL) filsD).factorEquilibre >= 0)
                return rotationG();
            else {
                filsD = ((NoeudAVL) filsD).rotationD();
                return rotationG();
            }
        }
    }

    public NoeudAVL insertion(int data) {
        if (data <= this.data) {
            if (filsG != null) {
                int oldfactorEquilibre = ((NoeudAVL) filsG).factorEquilibre;
                filsG = ((NoeudAVL) filsG).insertion(data);
                if ((((NoeudAVL) filsG).factorEquilibre != oldfactorEquilibre)
                        && (((NoeudAVL) filsG).factorEquilibre != 0)) {
                    factorEquilibre--;
                }
            } else {
                filsG = new NoeudAVL(data);
                factorEquilibre--;
            }
        } else {
            if (filsD != null) {
                int oldfactorEquilibre = ((NoeudAVL) filsD).factorEquilibre;
                filsD = ((NoeudAVL) filsD).insertion(data);
                if ((((NoeudAVL) filsD).factorEquilibre != oldfactorEquilibre)
                        && (((NoeudAVL) filsD).factorEquilibre != 0)) {
                    factorEquilibre++;
                }
            } else {
                filsD = new NoeudAVL(data);
                factorEquilibre++;
            }
        }
        if ((factorEquilibre < -1) || (factorEquilibre > 1))
            return equilibrer();
        return this;
    }

}

public ArbreAVL() {
    super();
}

public ArbreAVL(int cle) {
    super(cle);
}

public ArbreAVL(int cle, Noeud filsG, Noeud filsD) {
    super(cle, filsG, filsD);
}

/*
 * EN prenant soin de rééquilibrer l’arbre à chaque étape. On reprend
 * simplement les méthodes déjà écrites pour un arbre binaire de recherche
 */
public void insertion(int data) {
    if (isVide())
        super.insertion(data);
    else
        racine = ((NoeudAVL) racine).insertion(data);
}

public void supprimer(int data) {
    super.supprimer(data);
    this.racine = ((NoeudAVL) racine).equilibrer();

}
}
```

Comment: Provide a [SHORT, self-contained, compilable example](http://sscce.org/) that we could copy and paste to see the result you're getting. It's very unlikely that anyone will search through 300+ lines of code to try to find out what you're doing wrong.

Comment: Henry Keiter sorry can youu help me it take for me more than 8h

Answer (score 1):

In `ArbreAVL` constructors, you are using `Arbre` constructors, by calling `super()`.
They are creating `Noeud` objects, that you will later cast to `NoeudAVL`.

In fact, your `ArbreAVL` class is assuming all elements are `NoeudAVL`, which is definitely not the case. Either remove this assumption (by using `instanceof` tests?) or rework your code deeply, by using Generics for example.

Comment: i see but it work before 4h in this way, there is any sample solution i dont know generics

Comment: *Simple* but not smart, you can replace `super()` calls by creating `NoeudAVL` objects, since `filsG` and `filsD` are protected variables.

Comment: AFAIK, I'm not supposed to do your homework. If *it work before 4h in this way*, you should be able to go back to a working state quickly. Maybe your IDE can help? *Local History* feature in Eclipse could be helpful sometimes!